# Auto suggestion in text field with data from Google API

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, gluon-mobile

I want to make an autocomplete text field with suggestions where data is from the Google API - updated after each new key pressed.
For now, I have a method that downloads 5 suggestions and updates them when another key is pressed.

I've tried `AutoCompleteTextField` from Gluon, but it didn't work out well.

```java
public class Controller {
    Weather weather = new Weather();
    GooglePlaces googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

    @FXML
    AutoCompleteTextField<String> autoCompleteTextField = new AutoCompleteTextField<>();

    @FXML
    public void setAutoComplete() throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String[]> places = googlePlaces.predictPlaces("New yo");

        autoCompleteTextField.setCompleter(s -> {
            ArrayList<String> autoplaces = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < places.size(); i++) {
                autoplaces.add(places.get(i)[0]);
            }
            System.out.println("test");
            return autoplaces;
        });
    }
}
```

Here I tried to add 5 suggestions from `"New yo"` phase without updating after each new key, but it didn't work either as it doesn't show anything. `"test"` isnt printed in the console.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57612219/9278333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that you need to call `setCompleter()` in a method called `initialize()`:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        autoCompleteTextField.setCompleter(input -> {
            List<String[]> places = googlePlaces.predictPlaces(input);
            // ...
        });
    }
}
```

Also see:

- [JavaFX FXML controller - constructor vs initialize method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785417/javafx-fxml-controller-constructor-vs-initialize-method)
- [Is there a counterpart to @FXML initialize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913422/is-there-a-counterpart-to-fxml-initialize)